# CRM 2011 - Display all entities in option set

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I just started working with Dynamics CRM 2011 and need to do some tasks but I simply don't know how. Really hope you can help me with this.

I need to set the values for a picklist(option set) through code behind, it should display all published entities in the solution everytime the form of my custom entity is loaded.
I've searched the web and all I found was the next piece of code, but I absolutely have no idea what to do with is (yeah, I'm newbie, didn't you notice):

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest req = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();
req.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Privileges;
req.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse resp = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)service.Execute(req);
```

I tried to do the same with some JScript samples I found on the SDK but I still couldn't manage to insert the values into the picklist. Please give a hint or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I think, you should create an entity and put a lookup on form instead.
I've never seen using a picklist for dynamic data, I use them only for static.
They're like global enums.
But, they say about **addOption** at [MSDN Xrm.Page.ui Control methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addOption) web page.
Have you tried this one?

Comment: I first thought of a lookup but it can only point to the records of an entity and not the entity itself, am I right?